# Inheritance with an override function

Tags: c++

I'm looking at some C++ example code, which effectively has the following:

```
class Foo : public mynamespace::Bar
{
public:

    Foo()
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }

    void Delta() override
    {
        // Do some stuff

        Bar::Delta();
    }
};
```

I am having trouble understanding why the line `Bar::Delta();` exists. Given that class `Foo` inherits class `Bar`, then surely when `Foo::Delta()` is called, this overrides anything existing in `Bar::Delta()`, and hence this line is redundant.

Or am I misunderstanding this whole inheritance thing? Maybe `override` doesn't override everything?

Comment: Sometimes the base class has some useful tasks to perform regardless of being overridden.

Comment: `Bar::Delta()` calls `Bar::Delta` - this function still exists, `override` is just to make sure there was actually a `virtual` function with that same signature - which will result in compile error if there wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Bar::Delta();
```

is a function call. Isn't that what it looks like?

It's calling the base class version of `Delta` - by explicitly qualifying it as `Bar::Delta` - *in addition* to whatever extra stuff `Foo`'s version does.

---

> Maybe override doesn't override everything?

The `override` keyword just asks the compiler to verify you're really overriding a virtual function - otherwise, it's easy to accidentally write a new function which doesn't override anything (eg. because a parameter type is slightly different, or one version is const-qualified, or you changed the base class and forgot to update the derived class, or ...).

Here you *are* overriding the virtual function. That doesn't stop the base class implementation from *existing*, and as you've seen you can still call it.

---

You can (and should) test your intuition about this sort of thing yourself. Consider the trivial test code below. What do you think it will do?

Now actually run it. Were you right? If not, which part was unexpected?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Bar {
    virtual void Delta() {
        cout << "Bar::Delta\n";
    }
};

struct Foo : public Bar {
    void Delta() override
    {
        cout << "Foo::Delta\n";
        Bar::Delta();
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "b.Delta()\n";
    Bar b;
    b.Delta();

    cout << "f.Delta()\n";
    Foo f;
    f.Delta();

    cout << "pb->Delta()\n";
    Bar *pb = &b;
    pb->Delta();

    cout << "pb->Delta()\n";
    pb = &f;
    pb->Delta();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a common pattern. In fact, the `::` syntax for calling an overridden member function is there specifically for this situation.

It is very common for member function in a base class to perform some computation or action which can be done independently of the derived class, and let the derived class do things specific to the derivation.

Here is a fictitious example:

```
class Stock {
protected:
    double totalDividend;
    double baseDividend;
    double adjustmentFactor;
public:
    Stock(double d, double a)
    : baseDividend(d), totalDividend(d), adjustmentFactor(a) {
    }
    virtual void double ComputeDividend() {
        return totalDividend * adjustmentFactor;
    }
};

class SpecialStock {
private:
    double specialDividend;
public:
    SpecialStock(double d, double sd, double a)
    : Stock(d, a), specialDividend(sd) {
    }
    virtual void double ComputeDividend() override {
        // Do some preparations
        totalDividend = baseDividend + specialDividend;
        // Call the overridden function from the base class
        return Stock::ComputeDividend();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe override doesn't override everything?

The override specifier can be used to make compile-time checks when overriding a function that the function being overridden is virtual and is in fact being overridden.

> why the line Bar::Delta(); exists

This line calls the base `Delta` function which might have some useful tasks to perform even though you have overridden it.

A simple example:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void Foo()
    {
        // run tasks that are common to all derived types
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void Foo() override
    {
        Base::Foo(); // we have to call this explicitly
        // run tasks specific to the derived type
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to misunderstand what `override` means in `c++`. You should not really bother by it for your case. It's like a normal virtual function. `override` keyword is just a safety mechanism to ensure that a base class has matching function. It doesn't change anything other than semantic compile-time checks.

It is somewhat useful to guard against typical mismatches, such a `const` vs non-`const` versions, etc.

The virtual method mechanism does not replace the original member functions. It still is there in the `Derived` object. What happens is that a level of indirection is introduced, so a call to `base.foo()` uses a function pointer to call correct implementation which is `Derived::Foo()` in your case. But `Base::Foo()` still exists, and this is the syntax to "access" it. You can look up how exactly it work by searching materials on `virtual` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Delta in foo is a virtual method which "does some stuff" and then calls the base class's implementation of Delta.

**override** does not override anything, declaring the method as virtual does that. override is just for the compiler to throw syntax error in case the parent class doesn't have the Delta method.